# Recording network traffic on one linux box, transferring it to another in real time

Tags: linux, tcpdump, pcap

I have a situation where I want to capture all of the network traffic on one Linux box (currently using tcpdump) but have that data transferred in real time to another Linux on a separate (but connected) network. Essentially I have

```
[network i'm curious about]---[eth0. Linux box eth1]----[separate network]---[eth0 monitoring Linux box]
```

What I'm doing now is saving everything to a pcap and periodically transferring the pcap over to the monitoring Linux box. This works, but is highly inefficient and definitely not real time. Is there a way to make tcpdump save the pcap to a data stream I can proxy over to the monitoring box without setting up something like NFS or SMB? I consider the Linux box that is doing the tcpdump suspect at best and don't want to offer up a writable share on the monitoring box.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions! This really helps me out a lot. I hope I can return the favor someday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On monitoring_Linux_box:
`# nc -l -k -p 1234 > /var/tmp/pcap`

On Linux box:
`# tcpdump -U -w - | nc monitoring_Linux_box 1234`

Comment: I think this one is my best bet given that it has less of a security concern (no need to log in to the monitoring box from the recording box). Thanks!!

Comment: How does this avoid an infinite loop? Capture data, send it, capture that sent data, send it again, capture all that sent data, send it yet again...

Comment: Add `not port 1234` to tcpdump command line.

Answer (score 3):

From the monitoring box:

```
# ssh root@otherbox tcpdump -n -i eth0 -w - | program_that_takes_pcap_on_input
```

Answer (score 1):

Will a live capture over SSH work?

```
ssh -t remotehost 'sudo tcpdump [options]'
```

or if you use root..

```
ssh root@remotehost 'tcpdump [options]'
```

(Make sure to exlude your SSH traffic from the capture.)

If you want to watch it on-screen and save the output to a file, pipe to `tee`.

Comment: It isn't actually required to ignore SSH. A much cleaner solution would be to listen only on eth0.

Comment: May not be what you always want.  Since you might be looking for SSH traffic from others.  You should be able to part out the **SSH_CONNECTION** environment variable, which will include the client IP, client port, destination host, and destination port.  Then only exclude the traffic unique to that individual connection.

Comment: I am not suggesting to filter all SSH traffic. I think you've misunderstood. I can't imagine why you'd want to capture the SSH session of the host you are forwarding the `tcpdump` to... The question was to monitor another network remotely.